# Persist an Array of CLLocationCoordinate2D in Realm Database

Tags: swift, realm

I'm writing a location based application where i need to save an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` in my Realm model. What would be the best way to do that? Should i define a new model object for coordinates and use `List` to save that array or is there a better to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said it, the best approach would be creating your own models for storing coordinates. You can have class named `Location` that will be model for `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and other Realm objects can persist it using `List<Location>` or just `Location`.

Define `Location` class:

```
class Location: Object {
    dynamic var latitude = 0.0
    dynamic var longitude = 0.0

    /// Computed properties are ignored in Realm
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

And object that persists them:

```
class SomeObject: Object {
    let coordinates = List<Location>()
}
```

And you will be able to access `CLLocationCoordinate2D` via `coordinate` property. For example:

```
someObject.coordinates[0].coordinate
```